# Cakephp pagination and custom urls

Tags: routes, pagination, cakephp-2.0, custom-url

I am using custom theme in my website. My theme url is: http:/localhost/main/theme

I need pagination to display all users in a page. I want to set up pagination url look like this:

http:/localhost/main/theme/user/page:1

This is my route:

```
Router::connect('/main/:theme/user/', 
  array('controller' => 'custom_themes', 'action' => 'user'),
        array(
       'pass' => array('theme'),
       'theme' => '[a-z]+'
  )
);
```

Pagination page is:

```
$this->paginator->options(array('url'=> array(
'controller' => 'custom_themes', 
'action' => 'user',
'theme'=>$this->params['theme'])
));
```

But I am getting wrong url. I can not find out the problem. Please help me.

Comment: What (wrong) url did you get?